# Conditional FilterProvider for WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, action-filter, csrf-protection

I have an ASP.NET MVC / WebAPI / AngularJS application in which I want to implement CSRF protection. I have found some great solutions on this, but am missing one piece of the puzzle. I want to be able to automatically apply a custom AuthorizationAttribute to API nonsafe methods (POST, PUT etc). I hope someone can help.

On the MVC side, I am using the MVC AntiForgeryToken in conjunction with [Phil Haacked's ConditionalFilterProvider](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/04/24/conditional-filters.aspx/), configured to apply the ValidateAntiForgeryToken attribute to all POST methods. The technique is explained in [this post](http://kylehodgson.com/2013/01/08/asp-netmvc-web-security-basics-csrf/). The code for the ConditionalFilterProvider is listed below:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

public class ConditionalFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly
      IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> _conditions;

    public ConditionalFilterProvider(
      IEnumerable<Func<ControllerContext, ActionDescriptor, object>> conditions)
    {
        _conditions = conditions;
    }

    public IEnumerable<Filter> GetFilters(
        ControllerContext controllerContext,
        ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return from condition in _conditions
               select condition(controllerContext, actionDescriptor) into filter
               where filter != null
               select new Filter(filter, FilterScope.Global, null);
    }
}
```

For WebAPI, I'm using [AngularJS's CSRF protection mechanism](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http), packaged it up with some helper classes for easy implementation on the server, and I'm decorating the API methods with a custom AuthorizeAttribute, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15574486/angular-against-asp-net-webapi-implement-csrf-on-the-server).

All this works as intended, but I'd like to go one step further. Following the pattern used for the MVC controllers, I want to create a ConditionalFilterProvider that can be used with WebAPI controllers so that I can ensure that all POST methods are automatically decorated with my custom AuthorizeAttribute.

However, though I've had a stab at creating a ConditionalFilterProvider for WebAPI, I'm not sure I have it right, and can't test it as I don't know how to register it. What I've come up with is:

```
using System.Web.Http;

public class ConditionalApiFilterProvider : IFilterProvider
{
    private readonly
      IEnumerable<Func<HttpConfiguration, HttpActionDescriptor, object>> _conditions;

    public ConditionalApiFilterProvider(
      IEnumerable<Func<HttpConfiguration, HttpActionDescriptor, object>> conditions)
    {
        _conditions = conditions;
    }

    public IEnumerable<FilterInfo> GetFilters(
        HttpConfiguration configuration,
        HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor)
    {
        return from condition in _conditions
               select condition(configuration, actionDescriptor) into filter
               where filter != null
               select new FilterInfo(filter as IFilter, FilterScope.Action);
    }
}
```

And to register it in Application_Start (this doesn't work):

```
    private void ConfigureValidateCsrfHeaderAttribute()
    {
        //Configure a conditional filter
        string[] nonSafeMethods = { "post", "put", "delete" };
        IEnumerable<Func<HttpConfiguration, HttpActionDescriptor, object>> conditions =
            new Func<HttpConfiguration, HttpActionDescriptor, object>[] {
                    ( c, a ) => nonSafeMethods.Contains("need HTTP method here") ?
                    new ValidateCsrfHeaderAttribute() : null
            };

        var provider = new ConditionalApiFilterProvider(conditions);

        // This line adds the filter we created above
        FilterProviders.Providers.Add(provider);        //incorrect provider registration
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Discovered how to register a custom IFilterProvider for WebAPI, tested the solution and it works correctly. The code needed to register the provider is:

```
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

private void ConfigureValidateCsrfHeaderAttribute()
{
    //Configure a conditional filter
    HttpMethod[] nonSafeMethods = { HttpMethod.Post, HttpMethod.Put, HttpMethod.Delete };
    IEnumerable<Func<HttpConfiguration, HttpActionDescriptor, object>> conditions =
        new Func<HttpConfiguration, HttpActionDescriptor, object>[] {
                ( c, a ) => nonSafeMethods.Any(m => a.SupportedHttpMethods.Contains(m)) ?
                new ValidateCsrfHeaderAttribute() : null
    };

    var provider = new ConditionalApiFilterProvider(conditions);

    // This line adds the filter we created above
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Add(typeof(IFilterProvider), provider);
}
```